# angular reactive forms remove formArray elements after save

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In angular 5 I have a form with user can add multiple records of charges which can save at once. after save need to remove those records and go back to initial state with one row. I have tried as following code it goes to initial state but the validation is firing when go back to that state.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.fastPostingForm = this.fb.group({
      Charges: this.fb.array([
        this.initCharge()
      ])
    });
}

initCharge() {
    return this.fb.group({
      room: ['', Validators.required],
      transactionCode: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: [1, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(9999)]],
      window: ['', Validators.required],
      reservationId: [''],
      rsv:[{}]
    });
  }

  addCharge() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.fastPostingForm.controls['Charges'];
    control.push(this.initCharge());
    console.log(control.length);
  }

 saveForm(){
        //save process

        //clear form and remove form array elements

        this.fastPostingForm = this.fb.group({
      Charges: this.fb.array([
        this.initCharge()
      ])
    });

  }
```

In the UI validation is done using following condition for each control.

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="!fastPostingForm.controls.Charges.controls[i].controls.room.valid && fastPostingForm.controls.Charges.controls[i].controls.room.touched">message
</mat-error
```

>

Comment: Did you tried `this.fastPostingForm.reset();`?

Comment: yes, it does not remove additional rows which were added.

Comment: But did you try reset() after saving form and removing additional rows?

Comment: yes, tried. also doesnot work,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
saveForm(){

 this.fastPostingForm = this.fb.group({
      Charges: this.fb.array([
        this.initCharge()
 ])
 this.fastPostingForm.markAsUntouched();
 this.fastPostingForm.markAsPristine();
 this.fastPostingForm.updateValueAndValidity();

 });
```

Comment: try to add this also this.fastPostingForm.markAsPristine();

Comment: can you create stackbitz

Comment: *ngIf="!fastPostingForm.controls.Charges.controls[i].controls.room.valid && fastPostingForm.controls.Charges.controls[i].controls.room.touched" I have used this condition in UI.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the group again. You can simply remove all the elements from the `FormArray`. Use :

`(<FormArray>this.fastPostingForm.controls.Charges).controls.splice(0, (<FormArray>this.fastPostingForm.controls.Charges).controls.length);`

then call the `addCharge()` to add the default first element.

Comment: it gives me a error.   Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'AbstractControl' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: My bad, missed the charges controls. You need to get the `Charges` as a `FormArray`, then you can splice the controls like any other array.

Comment: but how to solve validation firing issue. after calling addcharge()  function the input's validation is firing. need to go pack to the initial state.

Comment: If the form is displayed on the UI, validators will be fired every time a control is rendered on UI.

Comment: but initial loading of the page does not firing any validation messages

Comment: It will fire. You may need to check the condition you have put to display the validation/error messages.

Comment: *ngIf="!fastPostingForm.controls.Charges.controls[i].controls.room.valid && fastPostingForm.controls.Charges.controls[i].controls.room.touched"  I have used this condition in UI.

Comment: it doesn't fire initially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185195/discussion-between-sachin-gupta-and-manoj-sanjeewa).

Comment: can you tell me how to delete single item using the above method?